# Why does this recursive function return the wrong value?

Tags: c++, recursion

I continue to run into an issue in building a recursive function where its returned value is different from the value I expect it to return. I'm fairly certain it relates to the recursive nature of the function, but I don't understand what is happening.

```
int foo(std::string, int = 0);

int main() {
std::string testString = "testing";
std::cout << foo(testString);
}

int foo(std::string givenString, int numberToReturn) {
    if (givenString.length() == 0) {
        std::cout << "Number to return before actually returning: " << numberToReturn << "\n";
        return numberToReturn;
    }
    if (true) {
        numberToReturn++;
    }
    std::string newString = givenString.erase(0, 1);
    foo(newString, numberToReturn);
}
```

In this minified example, I have function foo with a string and an int with a default value of 0. Given the string "testing" and no integer, I would expect the recursive function to increment numberToReturn for each call and pass the new value to the next call. This must be partly right because if I cout numberToReturn when I reach the base case, I get the expected value (which in this case it would be 7). But as soon as I return that value, it changes to a much larger number (6422160 in my case).

So with that said, why does the number change on return and how do I prevent that change from happening or otherwise return the correct/expected value?

**Edit: For anyone with a similar problem in the future, my issue was that each recusrion call must return something, not just the last one. In my case, returning the last line of function foo solves the issue. Not returning something for every function call leads to undefined behavior.**

Comment: "_why does the number change on return_" What return? You only return if `givenString.length() == 0` is true - otherwise you are falling off the end of the function without returning anything, which is undefined behavior,

Comment: Change your compiler settings to catch warnings and to treat all warnings as errors. It will save you a lot of headaches. It would have caught the problem you're having now.

Comment: @Algirdas I'm sorry, but I don't understand the issue. If I don't return, the function calls itself until the base case is true. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Then you return nothing. What do you think `int f(int n) { if(n == 0) return 42; f(n - 1); }` should do?

Comment: @PasserBy I would think that it would return 42 on the n + 1 call, no? Because that seems to work here. How does this translate to my slightly-longer example?

Comment: This is where you [get an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). What will `f(3)` do?

Comment: @ChanceH Assume `n = 1`. The `f(1)` calls `f(0)`. After `f(0)` returns, control goes back to the `f(1)` and reaches `}` without returning anything.

Comment: PasserBy, f(3) would still return 42 (after four calls). @HolyBlackCat I think it's starting to make sense, but the example seems to work just as I would expect without the return once the control goes back to f(1). Why then does the example you provide work without the return at the end of each call, but my example does not?

Comment: It might work by accident, it's UB after all.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Your function must always end with return, if it doesn't your function will return some random uninitialised value. For example

```
int foo( int x )
{
  if ( x == 0 )
  {
    return x;
  }
  foo(x-1);
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
int foo( int x )
{
  if ( x == 0 )
  {
    return x;
  }
  foo(x-1);
  return someRandomValue();
}
```

what you actually want is:

```
int foo( int x )
{
  if ( x == 0 )
  {
    return x;
  }
  return foo(x-1);
}
```

Comment: No. It won't _"return some random uninitialised value"_, it is called undefined behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was under the impression that as long as there was a return at the end of the recursion (nth call) everything was fine, but it appears that I need to always have a return at the end of each call. It seems like it is an easy fix because in your example you just return the function call, which makes sense. Does this sound about right?

Comment: @PasserBy yes, according to the standard the return value undefined behaviour but the actual behaviour in real programs is to return some random value depending on the calling convention which is likely to be the value which is currently stored in whichever register is used for the function result. I was trying to actually answer the question rather than blinding the poster with standardese.

Comment: No, you are misleading people. Claiming anything UB as otherwise is misleading. UB is not something you ignore in C++. Compilers **do** exploit this particular UB, even if we're talking about practicalities

Comment: @PasserBy OK so show me a program and compiler combination where missing a return on a function returning a scalar behaves differently than what I've stated.

Comment: @AlanBirtles [Enjoy](https://godbolt.org/g/seqK6t). Now stop posting plainly incorrect stuff.